# google places api icons list

Tags: android, icons, google-places-api

Do you know any resource that we can find all the icons that google provides for places ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I have not seen definitive list. Here is a [site with pictures linked](http://www.devedge.de/google-places-api/icons).

And below are lists broken down for easy copy/paste in alphabetical order:

- [[image] **airport** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/airport-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/airport-71.png)
- [[image] **amusement** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/amusement-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/amusement-71.png)
- [[image] **aquarium** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/aquarium-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/aquarium-71.png)
- [[image] **art_gallery** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/art_gallery-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/art_gallery-71.png)
- [[image] **atm** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/atm-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/atm-71.png)
- [[image] **baby** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/baby-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/baby-71.png)
- [[image] **bank_dollar** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/bank_dollar-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/bank_dollar-71.png)
- [[image] **bank_euro** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/bank_euro-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/bank_euro-71.png)
- [[image] **bank_pound** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/bank_pound-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/bank_pound-71.png)
- [[image] **bank_yen** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/bank_yen-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/bank_yen-71.png)
- [[image] **barber** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/barber-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/barber-71.png)
- [[image] **bar** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/bar-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/bar-71.png)
- [[image] **baseball** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/baseball-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/baseball-71.png)
- [[image] **beach** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/beach-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/beach-71.png)
- [[image] **bicycle** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/bicycle-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/bicycle-71.png)
- [[image] **bowling** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/bowling-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/bowling-71.png)
- [[image] **bus** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/bus-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/bus-71.png)
- [[image] **cafe** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/cafe-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/cafe-71.png)
- [[image] **camping** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/camping-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/camping-71.png)
- [[image] **car_dealer** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/car_dealer-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/car_dealer-71.png)
- [[image] **car_rental** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/car_rental-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/car_rental-71.png)
- [[image] **car_repair** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/car_repair-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/car_repair-71.png)
- [[image] **casino** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/casino-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/casino-71.png)
- [[image] **civic_building** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/civic_building-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/civic_building-71.png)
- [[image] **convenience** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/convenience-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/convenience-71.png)
- [[image] **courthouse** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/courthouse-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/courthouse-71.png)
- [[image] **dentist** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/dentist-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/dentist-71.png)
- [[image] **doctor** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/doctor-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/doctor-71.png)
- [[image] **electronics** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/electronics-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/electronics-71.png)
- [[image] **fitness** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/fitness-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/fitness-71.png)
- [[image] **flower** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/flower-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/flower-71.png)
- [[image] **gas_station** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/gas_station-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/gas_station-71.png)
- [[image] **generic_business** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png)
- [[image] **generic_recreational** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_recreational-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_recreational-71.png)
- [[image] **geocode** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png)
- [[image] **golf** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/golf-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/golf-71.png)
- [[image] **government** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/government-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/government-71.png)
- [[image] **historic** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/historic-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/historic-71.png)
- [[image] **jewelry** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/jewelry-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/jewelry-71.png)
- [[image] **library** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/library-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/library-71.png)
- [[image] **lodging** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/lodging-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/lodging-71.png)
- [[image] **monument** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/monument-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/monument-71.png)
- [[image] **mountain** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/mountain-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/mountain-71.png)
- [[image] **movies** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/movies-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/movies-71.png)
- [[image] **museum** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/museum-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/museum-71.png)
- [[image] **pet** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/pet-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/pet-71.png)
- [[image] **police** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/police-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/police-71.png)
- [[image] **post_office** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/post_office-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/post_office-71.png)
- [[image] **repair** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/repair-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/repair-71.png)
- [[image] **restaurant** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png)
- [[image] **school** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/school-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/school-71.png)
- [[image] **shopping** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/shopping-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/shopping-71.png)
- [[image] **ski** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/ski-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/ski-71.png)
- [[image] **stadium** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/stadium-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/stadium-71.png)
- [[image] **supermarket** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/supermarket-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/supermarket-71.png)
- [[image] **taxi** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/taxi-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/taxi-71.png)
- [[image] **tennis** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/tennis-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/tennis-71.png)
- [[image] **train** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/train-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/train-71.png)
- [[image] **travel_agent** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/travel_agent-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/travel_agent-71.png)
- [[image] **truck** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/truck-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/truck-71.png)
- [[image] **university** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/university-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/university-71.png)
- [[image] **wine** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/wine-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/wine-71.png)
- [[image] **worship_christian** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/worship_christian-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/worship_christian-71.png)
- [[image] **worship_general** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/worship_general-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/worship_general-71.png)
- [[image] **worship_hindu** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/worship_hindu-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/worship_hindu-71.png)
- [[image] **worship_islam** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/worship_islam-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/worship_islam-71.png)
- [[image] **worship_jewish** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/worship_jewish-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/worship_jewish-71.png)
- [[image] **zoo** https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/zoo-71.png](https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/zoo-71.png)

Comment: Thanks Stickley, you shared really good information after 4 months, hope it will help some fellows.

Comment: Thank You, Stickley - your answer was very useful.  I have since found 39 more icons, which I hope you don't mind that I have added to yours, above.  I am using this list to cache the icons for an app that uses Google Places API.

Answer (score 2):

I found a couple more!

Bus - 
http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/bus-71.png

School - 
http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/school-71.png

Synagogue - 
http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/worship_jewish-71.png

Answer (score 1):

The whole list can be found at Google: https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types

Comment: Probably we should get all the icon list by 'http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/' + supported_types + '-71.png'

Comment: right (does anyone know what the 71 stands for? Or will it change from time to time? ) ... unfortunately the names in my link above don't always match with the icon names in your list Haidun. But I´m currently writing something  in iOS and as soon as I grabbed all images, i will post the names/links ...

Comment: It is a list of place types, not icons.

Comment: @HaldunYildiz no, you cannot get an icon that way — for example, a «gym» place type has no it's own icon (like many other types).